# Distribution statistics

Tags: distributions

I have the question "Examine if the transactions are evenly distributed over the two years."
The data-set i have got shows some sale over 2 years.
I't might be a simple question i have got, but sometimes i make everything sound harder in my head and then don't know what to do :/
Question: What should the first thing i do be when looking at my data. What shall i do to see if the data is evenly distributed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume "evenly" means uniformly, then you can just plot your data to get a sense of what's going on:
x-axis: the day (or hour, week etc.);
y-axis: the transaction count (count the number of transaction in each time frame (i.e if you chose "day" in the x-axis the it should be the number of transactions in that day.
plot it all, if it looks like a rectangle then it is close to being uniform (even).

Comment: you can reference the following for more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution

Comment: my answer wasn't very "mathematical" this it was obvious from the questions that it's not very precise...

Comment: Okay that helped so so much!

Comment: Question, can i do a 95% confidence interval test with H0 and H1?